# Making $f(z) = e^{\frac{2}{|z|}}$ continuous at $z=0$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Is it possible to define $f(0)$ for $f(z) = e^{\frac{2}{|z|}}$ so it's continuous in $z=0$? Let's suppose $z = x+iy$, then we'd look for this limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}e^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}$$

When $x$ and $y$ go to $0$, sholdn't $\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ explode, and therefore, $e^{\frac{2}{|z|}}$ explode too?

Comment: In fact $lim_{|z|\rightarrow 0\atop z\not=0}f(z)=+\infty$. Did you mean ? $$f(z) = e^{-\frac{2}{|z|}}$$

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. it was written like this in my PDF, but I think the negative version makes more sense

Comment: Like that, it is possible to extend continuously $f$ by $f(0)=0$.